# OS X gesture and the responder chain

Tags: macos, cocoa, gesture

I have a window with a content view that does several things, including managing an iOS like navigation controller.

The window's content view front most view is an invisible custom view set here to manage drag n drop all over the window, called DragNDropView.

Now I want to manage the swipe gesture to navigate (left swipe only)  in the navigation controller.
Unfortunately the DragNDropView catches the gesture (if I implement -(void)swipeWithEvent: and set acceptTouchEvents:YES on it), and I don't want that since I want the views behind it to catch it, so of course I set acceptTouchEvents to NO on the DragNDropView.

I'm suprised the gesture event does not "go down" the view hierarchy as the views below do have their acceptTouchEvents set to YES when the front most view has acceptTouchEvents set to NO.

If the front most view does not handle the gesture, the gesture event is not passed to the views behind it????
gestures handling seems to be in NSResponder, so I even expect my NSViewController subclass to handle it, but it seems I can't.

Can any one help me understanding the problem?

Comment: I think you got the issue yourself. The First responder expects a user response but you are asking its parent to interact on the first responder!!!

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean. The front most view (DragNDropView) is set to acceptTouchEvents : NO, so, imo, it should forward all gesture events in the responder chain no?